# How do I connecting my Dell E6410 to a TV via DisplayPort?

Tags: displayport

I am a week into getting used to linux using Ubuntu 12.04 and I am really impressed with it.

I'm having a bit off\ difficulty connecting my Dell laptop to my digital tv using the displayport. I know it works using Windows but I haven't managed to figure out how to hook it up using Ubuntu.

Comment: On my Dell laptop, I just modify NVIDIA X Server settings to configure a second monitor with displayport.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my Lenovo T420s.  I would plug in the DisplayPort and nothing would happen, the monitor would just go to sleep.

It turns out you have to run the Nvidia control panel and enable the monitor from X Server Display Configuration.  The name of the package, if you don't have it installed, is nvidia-settings.

If you have an ATI card, I don't know what works but I would assume there's some sort of ATI control panel.

[image: Screenshot of my particular setup (yours would vary but this is the screen you need to manage your DisplayPort connection from)]

**UPDATE**: this is no longer an issue in Precise Pangolin (Ubuntu 12.10).  I upgraded this morning and DisplayPort is recognized the same way my VGA was.

Comment: A screenshot of that panel would make this answer perfect!